# Populating purchase order interface tables?

Tags: oracle, oracleapplications

What are the mandatory fields in the following tables that I need to populate in order that they can pass validation and can be imported in the respective base tables

- PO_HEADERS_ALL (Purchasing documents open interface)
- PO_LINES_ALL (Purchasing documents open interface)
- PO_LINE_LOCATIONS_ALL (Purchasing documents open interface)
- PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL (Purchasing documents open interface)

Comment: I assume you are using some packaged application suite.  What packaged application suite are you using and what application within that suite are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These tables **ARE** the base tables. **You should not normaly write directly to them**.

The open interfaces of the Purchasing module (for EBS 11.5.10) are described in Metalink note **359295.1**. Review the documentation carefully before using the interfaces. Don't write directly to the base tables -- this could void your support.

Answer (score 3):

## PO_HEADERS_INTERFACE

1)DOCUMENT_TYPE_CODE   = This column will accept any of the following string.
              STANDARD
              BLANKET
              PLANNED   CONTRACT

2)VENDOR_NAME          =It  will accept valid vendor name . by using PO_VENDORS Table
                        we can findout wether vendorname is valid or not.

4)VENDOR_SITE_NAME     = PO_VENDOR_SITES_ALL

5)VENDOR_CONTACT_NAME  = PO_VENDOR_CONTACTS

6)SHIPTO           = HR_LOCATIONS  table will be use to find the location is valid
                         or not.

7)BILLTO           = HR_LOCATIONS  table will be use to find the location is valid
                         or not.

8)CREATION_DATE        =It should be in the Date Format.And also <=SYSDATE

9)AGENT_ID           = it should be valid agentID(Buyer ID) .By using PO_AGENTS table
                       we can find out wether agent_id is valid or not.

10)ORG_ID        =It should be Valid OrgID. By using hr_operating_units table we
                      can find wether it is valid or not.

11)AUTHORIZATION_STATUS = Valid status either APPROVED,INCOMPLETE,CANCELLED
12)CURRENCY_CODE    = Valid Currency Code from FND_CURRENCIES table
                      we can find wether valid currency code or not.

## PO_LINES_INTERFACE:

LINE_NUM        = Will accept only unique values.

LINE_TYPE   = Should be a Valid Line type. By using PO_LINE_TYPES we can findout 
                  wether it is valid or not.

ITEM        =It should be a valid Item by using MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B table we can 
                 find wether valid Item or not.

ItemDesc        = Item Desc also should be valid description

UOM_Code        =Should be valid UOM by using MTL_UNITS_OF_MEASURES table we can find
                  wether it is valid or not.

QUANTItY        =Will accept any Positive Number

unit_Price      = Will accept any Positive Number

NEED_BY_DATE    = date Format and >= PO creation Date(from PO Headers Interface table)

PROMISED_DATE   = date Format and >= PO creation Date(from PO Headers Interface table)

ORG_ID          =It should be Valid OrgID. By using hr_operating_units table we
                 can find wether it is valid or not.

SHIP_TO_ORG    =Valid ORg_ID

ShipTo_Loc     = Valid Shiping Location

### PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_INTERFACE:

interface_header_id

interface_line_id

interface_distribution_id

set_of_books_id                     :valid Set of Books ID   : Gl_sets_of_books

org_id                  :Valid OrgID         : HR_OPERATING_UNITS

destination_organization_id     : Valid Organization ID  : ORG_ORGANIZATION_ID

quantity_ordered                    : Positive Numer (as per the shippment level total)

Answer (score 0):

You're using Oracle Apps right?  Well, that's a complicated schema.  But you should be able to `DESCribe` the table in SQL*Plus or whatever IDE you're using.  In which case, the minmim set of columns you have to populate are the ones which are declared NOT NULL.

Comment: It would be a pretty bad idea to write directly to an APPS schema just using describe to gather information. This could lead to inconsistent/incoherent data.